# React + Firebase authentication: creating a new user without changing the current logged in user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I have an admin area in my ReactJS app, and I need to allow admin to create users without changing the current logged in user.

This question has already been asked and has an answer here:

[Firebase Auth state changes after creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487092/firebase-auth-state-changes-after-creating-new-user)

But the above it not tailored to ReactJS, and I didn't quite understand it. I am also not using the Firestore database, so I am not sure if the above answer works for me.

Here is the current function I am using for normal sign up:

```
import firebase from "../../firebase"; //a file where we have firebase initialization with the SDK


// Signing up with Firebase
export const signup = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(beginApiCall());
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(dataBeforeEmail => {
        console.log('checking for state')
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          console.log('sending email verification')
          user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
                   console.log("email successfully sent");
                 });
        });
      })
      .then(dataAfterEmail => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // Sign up successful
            dispatch({
              type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
              payload:
                "Your account was successfully created! Now you need to verify your e-mail address, please go check your inbox."
            });
          } else {
            // Signup failed
            dispatch({
              type: SIGNUP_ERROR,
              payload:
                "Something went wrong, we couldn't create your account. Please try again."
            });
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(apiCallError());
        dispatch({
          type: SIGNUP_ERROR,
          payload:
            "Something went wrong, we couldn't create your account. Please try again."
        });
      });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(apiCallError());
    dispatch({
      type: SIGNUP_ERROR,
      payload:
        "Something went wrong, we couldn't create your account. Please try again."
    });
  }
};
```

I don't know how to 'transform' the above function into something that will just create a user without signing them in (I know I will not be using `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, but that's as far as I could go).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What they mean to tell is you cannot achieve the desired feature using the client but you can make use of firebase admin sdk

Comment: I know that that is what they mean, but I don't really know how to use the firebase admin sdk

Comment: It's not at all related to react, you will have to init cloud functions or create an express server to make use of firebase-admin. Lot of great tutorials in yt