# How do I redirect after auth users register to collection in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to connect a user to the user collection in firestore. And after then,I'm trying to redirect login page.But not work.

I have implemented this page for reference
[How do I link auth users to collection in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485656/how-do-i-link-auth-users-to-collection-in-firestore)

```
var express = require('express');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
require("firebase/firestore");
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require('moment');

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "hogehoge",
  authDomain: "hogehoge.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://hogehoge.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "hogehoge",
  storageBucket: "hogehoge.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "hogehoge",
  appId: "hogehoge"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.firestore();
let auth = firebase.auth();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'register page' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var userName = req.body.user_name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var createdAt = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

// If there is any error stop the process.
  promise.catch(function (error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      console.log(`GOT ERROR: ` + errorCode)
  });

  // When no errors create the account
  promise.then(function () {
      var userUid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      db.collection('users').doc(userUid).set({
          email: email,
          name: userName,
          password: password,
          created_at: createdAt
      });

      res.redirect('/login');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

If I don't write a redirect,

```
//res.redirect('/login');
```

registration is successful, but page is timeout.

So I'm writing a redirect process(not comment out), but this time the registration process is not done.

How can I redirect after registration is complete?

Comment: You have to return the promise, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure but I would say that you have to fulfill your promise of your `db.collection('users').doc(userUid).set(...)`. So try this:

```
promise.then(function () {
      var userUid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      db.collection('users').doc(userUid).set({
          email: email,
          name: userName,
          password: password,
          created_at: createdAt
      }).then(function () {
           res.redirect('/login');
         });
});
```